# control styles in the text to image generation algorithm

Tags: image-generation, stable-diffusion, text-to-image, lora, generative-art

I am looking at the text to image generation code from sdxl. [huggingface lcm-lra-sdxl](https://huggingface.co/latent-consistency/lcm-l0ra-sdxl)

Let's take the code from there

```
import torch
from diffusers import LCMScheduler, AutoPipelineForText2Image

model_id = "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0"
adapter_id = "latent-consistency/lcm-lora-sdxl"

pipe = AutoPipelineForText2Image.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16, variant="fp16")
pipe.scheduler = LCMScheduler.from_config(pipe.scheduler.config)
pipe.to("cuda")

# load and fuse lcm lora
pipe.load_lora_weights(adapter_id)
pipe.fuse_lora()

prompt = "Self-portrait oil painting, a beautiful cyborg with golden hair, 8k"

# disable guidance_scale by passing 0
image = pipe(
             prompt=prompt, 
             num_inference_steps=4, ## suggest additional parameters here
             guidance_scale=0
           ).images[0]
```

Now in the above code. We are mentioning the image style in the prompt only. This way when style is mentioned in the prompt, we may or may not get in the same format as mentioned. Is there a way to pass the separate parameter above for example

```
# disable guidance_scale by passing 0
image = pipe(
             prompt=prompt, 
             num_inference_steps=4, ## suggest additional parameters here
             style = 'pencil drawing',
             negative_prompts = 'extra limbs, {{mutated}}, {{bad anatomy}}, imperfect eyes'
             guidance_scale=0
           ).images[0]
```